# arrayindexoutofboundexception: 0 with an initialized array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

OK so in my class file I have

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PriceArray
{
int n;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
double pArray[];

public PriceArray(int nBooks)
{
    pArray = new double[n];
    n = nBooks;
}

public void pEntry()
{
    double p;
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++)
{
    p=-1;
    while(p<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive price for item #" + i);
        p = sc.nextDouble();
        pArray[i] = p;
    }

}
}
```

and in my test file I have

```
public class PriceArrayTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n;
do
    {
System.out.println("Please enter a positive number of books in the         store");
n = sc.nextInt();
}while(n<0);

PriceArray store = new PriceArray(n);

store.pEntry();
```

when the pEntry method is called I am getting arrayindexoutofboundexception: 0 for the line
 pArray[i] = p;
 in the entry method, my question is why am I getting this error when the array has been initialized?

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch "n = nBooks;" to happen before "pArray = new double[n];"

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the value of `n` when you initialize `pArray` with `new double[n]`:

> ```
> int n;
> double pArray[];
>
> public PriceArray(int nBooks) {
>     pArray = new double[n];
>     n = nBooks;
> }
> ```

At that point in the code, `n` was not assigned a value yet.
Since it's an `int`, its value defaults to 0 in this case.

As a result, `pArray` effectively gets initialized with `new double[0]`,
an empty array, so referencing index 0 will be out of bounds.

One way to fix:

```
public PriceArray(int nBooks) {
    pArray = new double[nBooks];
    n = nBooks;
}
```

Another way:

```
public PriceArray(int nBooks) {
    n = nBooks;
    pArray = new double[n];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding the value of `n` in your code, so you don't get the value you read in.

[Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

(Or as mentioned you may just be using two different `n` without hiding.  The other `n` is simply uninitialized.)

This variable hides (or at least isn't the same as) the value you use in the other part of your code:

```
int n;
do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive number of books in the         store");
        n = sc.nextInt();  // <-- This 'n' hides the other n
```

And the other part of your code, which does not use the same value of `n`

```
public class PriceArray
{
    int n;                    // <-- a *DIFFERENT* 'n'
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double pArray[];


    public PriceArray(int nBooks)
    {
        pArray = new double[n];  // <-- This 'n' is not the same as the other
        n = nBooks;
```

Comment: I believe the code he posted is in two different classes so there is no field hiding. He had an issue because "n" was not initialised, so it uses its default value of 0 to initialise a double array with size 0.

Comment: Ah, OK, that wasn't really clear with his indentation.  So not really hiding, just two different `n`s.